# Getting Async/Await property inside an event listener

Tags: javascript, async-await, addeventlistener

I have a bit of JS that is making an API call, getting the value from the that call, and then using that value to set a `userReferrer` cookie when the user clicks the submit button on a login form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

async function getData() {
    const urlValue = parseInt(getUrlParameter('tm'), 10);
    const response = await fetch(`/core/nav?productGroupId=${urlValue}`)
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

const data = getData().then(data => data);

document.getElementById('sign-in-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event, data) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (data.ratings) {
        createCookie('userReferrer', data.ratings);
    }
    this.submit();
});
```

Although I'm passing the data obj to the event listener function, it's `undefined` inside the event listener when I try to log it. I can see in the inspector that the call is successfully made and if I log the value outside of the event listener I can see it. Ideas on how I can structure this so the returned API value is properly passed to or obtained within the event listener function?

Comment: It looks like the data param of the event listener function *hides* the fetched data in the enclosing scope.  The other issue is timing. There needs to be a away of preventing the submit until getData() has completed.

Comment: I find it confusing that you're reusing the variable name `data` for both the result of `getData` and for the argument to the `submit` handler.  It makes it unclear which `data.ratings` you mean.  You also say you're passing `data` obj to the event listener function, **but you're not**.  It's not clear to me what you think `.then(data => data)` accomplishes, but it probably doesn't do what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make sure `data` is populated, you need to `await` for the Promise that returns from `getData` to be resolved.

In other words, you need to make sure your code runs synchronously:

```
async function useData() {
  const data = await getData();
  document.getElementById('sign-in-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (data.ratings) {
        createCookie('userReferrer', data.ratings);
    }
    this.submit();
  });
}
```

Then you can just call it:

```
useData();
```

Note how this function doesn't require `await`, since we're not using its result. This means we don't have to wait for it, and it can just finish whenever it's finished doing its thing.

---

Alternatively, you can write the same code using syntax that's more similar to your original snippet:

```
getData().then((data) => {
  // Inside this scope `data` is already populated
  document.getElementById('sign-in-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (data.ratings) {
        createCookie('userReferrer', data.ratings);
    }
    this.submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right `data`?  You have two.  One is from the `getData` and the other is an argument to the `submit` listener.  I think your code is wrong.  The same problem existed in the original, in your defense, and the second `data` that hides the first is way off to the right, maybe you didn't see it?

Comment: @Wyck Thanks for noticing! The snippet was horizontally cut, so I didn't see this part (that I, indeed, just copied). I removed the second redundant argument altogether, since [the `submit` event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) only has a single one